# Add last element to an array from for loop

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-loop

I have a code like so...

```
for element in self.arr_Offline {
   self.arr_OfflineTemp.add(element)
   break
}
self.arr_Offline.removeObject(at: 0)
```

Here I'm looping through an array called `self.arr_Offline`, adding the first element from that array into another array called `self.arr_OfflineTemp` and immediately doing break so that the second array will have just one element and then once I'm outside the for-loop, I remove the added object from the main array by doing `self.arr_Offline.removeObject(at: 0)`

But I want to add the last element to `self.arr_OfflineTemp` instead of the first and then remove that last element from `self.arr_Offline`. It should look something like so...

```
for element in self.arr_Offline { // looping through array
   self.arr_OfflineTemp.add(lastElementOf'self.arr_Offline') //add last element
   break
}
self.arr_Offline.removeObject(at: 'last') //remove that last element that was added to `arr_OfflineTemp`
```

How can I achieve this..?

Answer (score 1):

First of all never use `NS(Mutable)Array` and `NS(Mutable)Dictionary` in Swift.

Native Swift Array has a convenient way to do that without a loop

First element:

```
if !arr_Offline.isEmpty { // the check is necessary to avoid a crash
    let removedElement = self.arr_Offline.removeFirst()
    self.arr_OfflineTemp.append(removedElement)
}
```

Last element:

```
if !arr_Offline.isEmpty {
    let removedElement = self.arr_Offline.removeLast()
    self.arr_OfflineTemp.append(removedElement)
}
```

And please drop the *unswifty* snake_case names in favor of camelCase

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the same approach with reversed() Swift:

```
for i in arr.reversed():
   // your code logic
```

After adding element, you can remove the last element from the list using this:

```
lst.popLast() or lst.removeLast()
```

Try this for the above code:

```
for element in self.arr_Offline.reversed() {
   self.arr_OfflineTemp.add(element)
   break
}
self.arr_Offline.popLast()
```

Is this something you are looking for?

Comment: ok @Priyanshu Tiwari. so you mean I can do `for element in self.arr_Offline.reversed { .. }`..but how do I do `lst.pop() or del lst[-1]`..?..

Comment: there is no method called pop in swift

Comment: use popLast() or removeLast()

Comment: for element in self.arr_Offline.reversed() {
   self.arr_OfflineTemp.add(element)
   break
}
self.arr_Offline.popLast()